# Error on converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
create table MobileUnit
(
    IDMobileUnit int identity  primary key,
    Type numeric null,
    Length numeric null,
    Width numeric null,
    Height numeric null
);
```

My task is to insert XML data into this table, and I have done this:

```
<MobileUnit>
    <Type  />
    <Length  />
    <Width  />
    <Height  />
</MobileUnit>

INSERT INTO MobileUnit (Type, Length, Width, Height)
    SELECT 
        Type = c.value('Type[1]', 'numeric(18,0)'),
        Length = c.value('Length[1]', 'numeric(18,0)'),
        Width = c.value('Width[1]', 'numeric(18,0)'),
        Height = c.value('Height[1]', 'numeric(18,0)') 
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/MobileUnit') MobileUnit(c)
```

The problem is, that I get an error when executing the code

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely, your input format just contains some strings in some of the values.... the code per se appears to be OK - with a proper input (all numbers with no fractional digits), it works fine

Comment: your windows settings may change '.' and ',' as decimal seperator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shred the XML values as nvarchar(20) and then use [try_convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) to convert them to numeric(18,0) or null...

```sql
create table MobileUnit
(
    IDMobileUnit int identity  primary key,
    Type numeric null,
    Length numeric null,
    Width numeric null,
    Height numeric null
);

declare @xml xml =
'<NIACList>
 <NIAC>
  <CommercialUnit>
   <MobileUnit>
    <Type  />
    <Length  />
    <Width  />
    <Height  />
   </MobileUnit>
   <MobileUnit>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <Length>2</Length>
    <Width>3</Width>
    <Height>4</Height>
   </MobileUnit>
  </CommercialUnit>
 </NIAC>
</NIACList>';

INSERT INTO MobileUnit (Type, Length, Width, Height)
    SELECT 
        [Type] = try_convert(numeric(18, 0), c.value('Type[1]', 'nvarchar(20)')),
        Length = try_convert(numeric(18, 0), c.value('Length[1]', 'nvarchar(20)')),
        Width = try_convert(numeric(18, 0), c.value('Width[1]', 'nvarchar(20)')),
        Height = try_convert(numeric(18, 0), c.value('Height[1]', 'nvarchar(20)'))
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/MobileUnit') MobileUnit(c);

select * from MobileUnit;
```

Which yields...

```
IDMobileUnit  Type  Length  Width  Height
           1  null    null   null    null
           2     1       2      3       4
```